# accessing types.h through man

Tags: 16.04, manpage

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have installed `manpages-posix-dev`.
It works for `unistd.h` but not for `sys/types.h`.
What command do I have to use to get manpages for `sys/types.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpages for headers from the `/usr/include/sys` tree are apparently prefixed by `sys_`

```
$ dpkg -L manpages-posix-dev | grep 'sys_'
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_ipc.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_mman.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_msg.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_resource.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_select.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_sem.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_shm.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_stat.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_statvfs.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_time.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_timeb.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_times.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_types.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_uio.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_un.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_utsname.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_wait.h.7posix.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/sys_socket.h.7posix.gz
```

So to see the manpage for `sys/types.h`, you would use

```
man sys_types.h
```

```
NAME
       sys/types.h - data types

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
```